# jQuery - Updating all the divs using wildcard selector

Tags: jquery

I've this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mVGf/), which is not working.

All I want to do is update all the `divs` starting with `mydiv`, with some text, onclick of the button. Am I doing something wrong or is it the wrong way of doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **[text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** instead of `val()` to set the text inside your divs:

```
$("#btn").click(function(e){
    $('[id^=mydiv]').text('Testing divs');
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working now. So stupid of my to use `val()` instead of `text()` :(

Comment: No worry, not only you but everyone must have mistakes to improve ourselves :-)

Answer (score 0):

For non-void elements you have to use [**`.text()`**](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to set its text.

Try,

```
$("#btn").click(function(e){
    $('[id^=mydiv]').text('Testing divs');
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4mVGf/1/)